# How to properly use a function that is recursive and receives a single argument?

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary

While trying to solve the following exercise...

> Define the function `binaryDigits`, that receives an Integer and
>   returns the amount of digits required to write such umber in binary
>   code.

... I found myself thinking that it is impossible to solve this problem by calling the function `binaryDigits` recursively because the only variable it receives is the actual number

I say this because the website states that while the tests it runs were succeeded, I didn't use recursion in the function `binaryDigits`.

so how could I even think of recursively call this function if I can't even tell how many times have I called it (and lets say that the number of times being called represent how many binary digits it takes to represent that number).

This is what I thought: please note that *I'm using recursion but in an auxiliary function that returns a list of the decimal values that binary digits represent* when the sum of that list is greater than the received number:

```
double = (2*)

listOfBinaryDigits list num | num > (sum list) = listOfBinaryDigits ([double(head list)]++list) num
                            | otherwise = list

binaryDigits num = length (listOfBinaryDigits [1] num)
```

Comment: How many digits do you need for 153? Now how many do you need for `div 153 10 == 15`? Or `div 15 10 == 1`? Or `div 1 10 == 0` (hint: assume you need only 0 digits for 0 itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an "iterative" solution:

```
binaryDigits = length . takeWhile (not . (==0)) . iterate (`div` 2)
```

You can also redefine it by recursing until you hit the bottom and sum the length on the way back. It will be a good exercise, so I kept the solution in a spoiler for you

> ```
> binaryDigits 0 = 0;
> binaryDigits x = 1 + binaryDigits (div x 2)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

No need for recursion or iteration. You may perhaps do with base 2 logarithm as follows;

```
binaryDigits :: (Floating a, Integral c, RealFrac a) => a -> c
binaryDigits n | n == 0    = 1
               | otherwise = 1 + (floor . logBase 2 $ n)
> binaryDigits 1453
> 11
```